# Felix FileInstall configuration in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, apache-felix

I'm trying to integrate the **Apache Felix FileInstall** bundle inside my Eclipse project, but I'm absolutely desperate about how to configure it properly.

I've tried to find the correct answer for days now, and still didn't get the correct one.

I've downloaded the **FileInstall** *jar* and imported it into my project like a *"Plug-In from existing Jar Archives"*.

The bundle works correctly, but I'm unnable to tell him what directory he  must watch for new bundles to install and start. In resume, **I just can't configure the bundle**, and I'm starting to feel somehow stupid.

Please any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the [configuration properties](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-file-install.html) as system properties while launching the OSGi container. Also have a look at answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662581/apache-felix-file-install-example/16667908) question.

In Eclipse (using PDE) you can specify it in the Preferences -> Target Platform -> Edit -> Arguments -> VM Arguments -> -Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=/path/to/dir

Comment: I'm currently using Equinox, will it work without using Felix? Thanks

Comment: Yes it should work fine. Have a look at [Felix FAQ](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-examples-and-presentations/apache-felix-osgi-faq.html#if-i-use-bundles-from-felix-will-my-application-be-tied-to-the-felix-framework) for more details

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I really don't know where to start. I don't even know what system properties I should change, or why system properties should be changed at all. I mean, I just want FileInstall to be executed for a certain directory, why is that so complicated?

Comment: File Install needs to know the directory name and that information is provided via system property. So if you specify the dir path through `felix.fileinstall.dir` then File Install bundle would read it and start watching that dir

Comment: Where should I specify that? If it's in a file, where should be located?

Comment: See the updated answer. It assumes you are using PDE Target Platform support. If you are using any other way to launch Equinox then let me know

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30688/discussion-between-chetan-and-asier-aranbarri)

Comment: finally I was able to configure this properly. Thanks for your time and effort, +1 and tick.